# Access violation in 3rd party DLL when loading from application compiled with Visual C++ 2019

Tags: exception, visual-c++, runtime, loadlibrary

I have used some 3rd party DLL (precisely: TRMPRO.DLL - i.e. Tsunami Record Manager - compiled with PowerBASIC in 2005) for many years with my application compiled with Visual C++ 2008 and it has been working OK, also in Windows 10, but when I am trying to load (with LoadLibrary function) this DLL from the same application recompiled with Visual C++ 2019, it causes an access violation, exception thrown. The DLL rather does not depend on Visual C++ runtime, so I can't see any reason of such a behavior. Is LoadLibrary function working differently with the newer Visual C++ runtime? Any other ideas?
The application and, of course, TRMPRO.DLL are 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I actually worked w/ J on this via email. The solution is to turn off DEP protection.
From J's email:

> The automatic project conversion from MSVC 2008 to MSVC 2019 doesn't
>   set the /NXCOMPAT option, and the unset option means prevention is on.

Comment: It was Don's idea to turn off Data Execution Prevention. If you set DEP to "Default" in MSVC 2008, linker treats it as "Off". Unfortunately, this default setting is automatically converted into the default setting in MSVC 2019, which is "On". Of course, it wouldn't be a problem if the DLL didn't do any weird things.